# What does superuser mean in the rights-extension of Yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am using the rights extension of Yii and get this error:

```
There must be at least one superuser!
```

I don't know what this `superuser` means since I am using the default authentication with user admin and demo. After reading the documentation of rights extension, I tried to configure rights with:

```
'rights'=>array(
    'superuserName'=>'admin',
    'install'=>true
),
```

But it doesn't work, I have searched the internet but got no result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to connect the user table with a table AuthAssignment, whose name has been declared in the array setting

```
'modules'=>array(
'rights'=>array(
    'superuserName'=>'admin',
     ),
 ),
```

then, you have to change the table AuthAssignment userid field that refer to field id on table user

Answer (score 5):

If you have installed user and rights like [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/423/installing-yii-users-and-rights-to-newly-created-yii-app/),
Just run this in your database:

```
INSERT INTO `AuthAssignment` (`itemname`, `userid`, `bizrule`, `data`) VALUES ('Admin', '1', NULL, 'N');
INSERT INTO `AuthItem` (`name`, `type`, `description`, `bizrule`, `data`) VALUES ('Admin', 0, 'Admin', NULL, 'N;');
```

**Note:** In the tutorial all table names of rights module are in lower case.

Answer (score 2):

The naming is a bit misleading, I stumbled upon that problem also.

`superuserName` should be named `superuserRole`, meaning that all users which are assigned to the role specified there are **super-users**.

Please note that `Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('whatever')` will always `return true` for **super-users**.

*See also [RAuthorizer.php](https://bitbucket.org/Crisu83/yii-rights/src/437267d8b1edd121ccb860b5a5f00203362ec3ae/components/RAuthorizer.php?at=default#cl-12):*

```
/**
* @property string the name of the superuser role.
*/
public $superuserName;
```

*and [RWebUser.php](https://bitbucket.org/Crisu83/yii-rights/src/437267d8b1edd121ccb860b5a5f00203362ec3ae/components/RWebUser.php?at=default#cl-25)*.

Answer (score 1):

there's a small hack,  line you have to comment out for it to work...

check official extension page comments

**EDIT**: I didn't want to post a link to **my own blog** because it looks like self-promoting but it's a very comprehensive solution to your problem I think : [installing yii-rights extension](http://queirozf.com/reminders/installing-yii-rights-extension)

Answer (score 1):

FWIW (since it's been so long), you have to grant one of your users the superuser role.

That role name is denoted in the `superuserName` property in the config file, as shown in your post.
This can be done directly via SQL, by updating the `authAssignment` table (its name may be different in your case, it is configurable).

```
INSERT INTO `authassignment` (`itemname`, `userid`, `bizrule`, `data`) VALUES ('admin', '1', NULL, 'N;');
```

Then, log in as the appropriate user (the one corresponding to id #1, in this particular case).

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use mysql database and table user not default authentication -it is just a example of authentication-. after you import user table
you should add a user with username "admin" -if u have "admin" in superuserName config-  in user table.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install it by following a post on the yii-forums - here is a permalink to my post:
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10556-extension-rights/page__view__findpost__p__229721